# $(this) and scope - passing a specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variety of `.img-drop-zones` and upon drop a file is read, I wish to display it on top of the specific drop zone it was placed on, but how do I get it? `$(this)` does not work because of scope, how can I pass it through?

```
 $('.img-drop-zone').on('drop', function(e){

        var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;

        $.each(files, function(index, file){

            p.file.read(file, function(content) {
                //how can I get the img-drop zone here?

            });

        }) 


    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(this) is what you need

```
 $('.img-drop-zone').on('drop', function(e){
        var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
        var dropJone = $(this);
        $.each(files, function(index, file){
            p.file.read(file, function(content) {
                //how can I get the img-drop zone here?
                //use dropJone here
          });
        }) 
});
```

Comment: `dropJone` != `drop zone`

Comment: Thanks, may I ask, how I can target the image inside dropzone? $(dropZone + 'img') doesnt work.

Comment: the html is just a standard <img>

Comment: @Sparky yups you are right, its a comment though but still edited that

Comment: @panthro try like dropJone.find("img"), for better help need to see some html too

Comment: Comment or not, anyone who couldn't answer the question, wouldn't be able to follow your answer.  It's better now, although not sure what a `Jone` is.  ;)

Answer (score 5):

Just declare an additional variable in the outer scope that you can refer to within the `$.each` closure:

```
var $this = $(this);

$.each(..., function() {
    // use $this here to refer to the img-drop-zone
});
```

When referring to an object to something that isn't a jQuery object it's more common to use `self` or `that`.

Comment: Will e.target suffice? Why not?

Comment: @rolodex it might, but jQuery provides `this` so why not use it?  ISTR also that `e.target` doesn't work right if using a delegated event handler, whereas jQuery ensures that `this` is correct.